# What is wrong with my template function using ifstream?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am implementing a template function to read a file and file-like entities into a vector line by line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T> vector<T> readfile(T ref1)
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    std::istream_iterator<T> is_i;
    std::ifstream file(ref1);
    std::copy(is_i(file), is_i(), std::back_inserter(vec));
    return vec;
}
```

I look to read a file using the following code in main:

```
int main()
{
    std::string t{"example.txt"};
    std::vector<std::string> a = readfile(t);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:
     "no match for call to '(std::istream_iterator, char, ...

Let me know if I need to supply more of the error message. Chances are I am just messing up something simple. But I can't understand why - using tutorials I have gotten this and I thought it to be a pretty good solution.

Comment: Can you provide the *whole* error?

Comment: Why do you call this function a function template? This function only works for `std::string` so in fact it is not function template per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apparently meant to turn `is_i` into a type but instead declared a variable of type `std_istream_iterator<T>`. You probably meant to write:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<T> is_i;
```

You should probably also decouple your template argument from the type used for the file name as the template is otherwise fairly restrictive:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> readfile(std::string const& name) {
    ...
}

std::vector<int> values = readfile<int>("int-values");
```

Comment: That correctly got it to do what I wanted! But I was under the assumption std::istream_iterator<T> was already a type, and is_i a variable of that type. I spose it makes little sense that that type exists before all this, hah.

Comment: Well, yes, `std::istream_iterator<T>` is a type but you tried to create objects using a variable of this type which doesn't work.